# Using one button to enable and stop a function rather than two buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently using two buttons (Go, Stop) to call and enable/disable my function.
But is it possible to use one button to call the function to disable or enable. Example, clicking the button will make it blue, this enables the function, clicking the button again will make it go white, this disables the button.

My current code is:

```html
<button id="go">Go</button>
<button id="stop">STOP!</button>
<div class="block"></div>
   <style>
  #draggable {
   width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
     padding: 0.5em;
     top:5%;
     left: 5%; }
  </style>
<script>
// Start animation
$( "#go" ).click(function() {
  $( ".block" ).draggable();
});
// Stop animation when button is clicked
$( "#stop" ).click(function() {
$( ".block" ).draggable( "disable" );
});
$( "#go" ).click(function() {
$( ".block" ).draggable( "enable" );
});

</script>
<button id="go">Go</button>
<button id="stop">STOP!</button>
<div class="block"></div>
   <style>
  #draggable {
   width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
     padding: 0.5em;
     top:5%;
     left: 5%; }
  </style>
<script>
// Start animation
$( "#go" ).click(function() {
  $( ".block" ).draggable();
});
// Stop animation when button is clicked
$( "#stop" ).click(function() {
$( ".block" ).draggable( "disable" );
});
$( "#go" ).click(function() {
$( ".block" ).draggable( "enable" );
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, all you need is something to keep track of state, like a flag

```
$("#go").on('click', function () {

    var flag = $(this).data('draggable');

    $(".block").draggable( flag ? 'disable' : 'enable' );

    $(this).data('draggable', !flag);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ks2nxz0m/1/)

Comment: @CasperRound - works swimmingly for me, added a Fiddle !

Comment: Just a question, how did you get it to grey out when disabled? I would like that for what I'm doing but on enable

Comment: I didn't do anything, it did that all by itself, so it's probably greyed out when disabled by default, I'm guessing part of the jQuery UI styles or something ?

Answer (score 0):

Could try jquery in your on click function

```
$(this).toggleclass("stop")
*insert code to test if class is stop"
```